# Catch exceptions on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke, synchronizationcontext

When developing winform applications it is common that you will have to just invoke to get the main GUI thread to do the GUI work.

`Invoke` are today obsolete(If I read correct), instead you are suppose to use the `SynchronizationContext` instead.

**The question is :** How do I handle exceptions? I have notice that sometimes the exception thrown on the "synced/invoked" thread is lost?

I do use the `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` but this does not help?

Comment: where did you read that `Invoke` was obsolete?

Comment: SynchronizationContext is the new fancy way to do it.  I wouldn't say that Invoke is obsolete, but it's no longer the preferred way.

Comment: So what do you want to do with this exception?  Do you just want some way of bringing down the whole app when a particular background thread crashes?  Do you want to update the UI based on the fact that there was an exception in another thread?

Comment: I want to log the exception to database.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Synchronization Context is nothing new, it's been there since .NET 2.0. It has nothing to do *specifically* with exception handling. Neither does it make `Control.Invoke` obsolete. In fact, `WinFormsSynchronizationContext`, which is the WinForms' implementation of synchronization context, uses `Control.BeginInvoke` for `Post` and `Control.Invoke` for `Send` methods.

> How do I handle exceptions? I have notice that sometimes the exception
>   thrown on the "synced/invoked" thread is lost?

There is a well-documented behavior behind "sometimes" here. `Control.Invoke` is a **synchronous call**, which propagates exceptions from inside the callback to the calling thread:

```
int Test()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Surpise from the UI thread!");
}

void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // UI thread
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
    {
        // pool thread
        try
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)Test);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

The benefit of using `SynchronizationContext` is in de-coupling the WinForms specifics. It makes sense for a portable library, which potentially may be used by WinForms, WPF, Windows Phone, Xamarin or any other client:

```
// UI thread
var uiSynchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
if (uiSynchronizationContext == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("SynchronizationContext.Current");

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
{
    // pool thread
    try
    {
        uiSynchronizationContext.Send(s => Test(), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
    }
});
```

Thus, with `Control.Invoke` (or `SynchronizationContext.Send`) you have an option to handle exceptions on the calling thread. You don't have such option with `Control.BeginInvoke` (or `SynchronizationContext.Post`), by design and by common sense. That's because `Control.BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, it queues a callback to be executed upon a future iteration of the message loop run by `Application.Run`.

To be able to handle exception thrown by an **asynchronous callback**, you'd need to actually observe the completion of the asynchronous operation. Before C# 5.0, you could have used events or `Task.ContinueWith` for that.

**Using an event:**

```
class ErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

event EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> Error = delegate { };

void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Error += (sError, eError) =>
        // handle the error on the UI thread
        Debug.Print(eError.Exception.ToString()); 

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
        {
            try
            {
                Test();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // fire the Error event
                this.Error(this, new ErrorEventArgs { Exception = ex });
            }
        }));
    });
}
```

**Using `ContinueWith`:**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    uiSynchronizationContext.Post(s => 
    {
        try
        {
            tcs.SetResult(Test());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    }, null);

    // observe the completion,
    // only if there's an error
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // handle the error on a pool thread
        Debug.Print(task.Exception.ToString());
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

});
```

Finally, **with C# 5.0, you can use `async/await`** and handle exceptions thrown asynchronously with the same convenience of `try/catch` you have for synchronous calls:

```
int Test()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Surpise from the UI thread!");
}

async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // UI thread
    var uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // pool thread
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => Test(), 
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                uiTaskScheduler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle the error on a pool thread
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You seems to know a lot about this! I do however think that you are making it a bit to complicated when you involve ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and Task.Factory.StartNew. All I do is uiSynchronizationContext.Send, I never creates a separate thread for this, why would I?

Comment: From what I can see all you really do is to place a try/catch block within the method where the SynchronizationContext sends the UI thread and then you handle the cache in one way or the other? So to simplifie it you are really suggesting that I have try/cache in the method that are triggered byt the SynchronizationContext and then handle the exception here?

Comment: @Banshee, if all you do is `uiSynchronizationContext.Send` and never create a thread, why do you need to use `Send` at all? It makes sense only if you call it from another thread. And that's why I used `QueueUserWorkItem`, to show how to call it from another thread.

Comment: You always have two options: handle an exception inside the `Post/Send` callback, or outside. I'm showing the later case, which is more involved, especially for asynchronous callback. To decide, what's right for any particular case, check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: This is really great, but if the exception is not handled on the calling thread or when using Post/BeginInvoke, why is not ThreadException or UnhandledException triggered?

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way for the ui thread to catch an exception from a different thread.

1) Create a method in your UI class that's designed to run on the UI thread, such as HandleExceptionFromThread(Exception ex);

2) Grab the SynchronizationContext from the ui thread.  You can get that by calling SynchronizationContext.Current.

3) The method that will be run on the second thread needs to take in the SynchronizationContext as a parameter.  You may need to do some dynamic casting from object to SyncrhonizationContact, but it shouldn't be too hard.

4) When an exception is caught, call uiContext.Send(HandleExceptionFromThead, ex) to synchronously, or uiContext.Post(HandleExceptionFromThead, ex) to asynchronously, send the exception to the method to be handled in the UI thread.

Here's some sample code of what I imagined.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    .....
    public void HandleExceptionFromThread(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    public void ButtonClickToRunThread(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Task task = new Task((state)=>
        {
            SynchronizationContext uiContext = state as SynchronizationContext;
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                uiContext.Post(HandleExceptionFromThread, ex);
            }
        }, syncContext);
        task.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the SynchronizationContext is set right at startup and its  available from wherever you are in the application. What you suggests is simple ty have a try, catch in the method that the SynchronizationContext.post is pointed at and in the catch simple log the exception as with all other exceptions?

Comment: Not quite.  The Post happens within the catch statement.  It's used to call a method within the UI thread.  It works the same as Invoke/BeginInvoke.  If all you want to do is log the exception, then you can do it in the second thread itself.  If you want to handle it in the UI thread with a notification to the user, then this is a simple way to do it.